# Read File from FTP and send stream

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy I have a requirement to read a file from an ftp site and send it as an stream back. Below code actually downloads to a local directory. How can I modify so I can send the stream.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils 
new FTPClient().with {
connect "abc.efg.pqr"
enterLocalPassiveMode()
login "xxx", "yyy"
changeWorkingDirectory "/xyz/pqr/"
def fileName = message.getInvocationProperty('fileName')
log.debug("File Name " + fileName)
def incomingFile = new File("/Users/abc/"+fileName)
incomingFile.withOutputStream { ostream -> retrieveFile fileName, ostream } 
disconnect()
```

Comment: send it back to where?

Comment: Can you show the endpoint code with the FTP code in the question?